# Firebug returning constant nsLoginManager error

Tags: firebug

I'm working on a project, and Firebug keeps on reporting a nsLoginManager error (which has nothing to do with my project.

It is disconcerting to see "3 errors" in the status bar on my browser only to open it up and see it's the effing nsloginmanager error message... AGAIN.

Here is the error:

```
[Exception... 
"Component returned failure code: 0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)  
[nsIRequest.name]"  nsresult: "0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)"
location: "JS    frame :: file:///Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/
components/nsLoginManager.js :: anonymous :: line 315"  data: no]file:///
Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/components/nsLoginManager.js
Line 315
```

Here is the relevant code form nsLoginManager.js:

```
        onStateChange : function (aWebProgress, aRequest,
                              aStateFlags,  aStatus) {

        // STATE_START is too early, doc is still the old page.
        if (!(aStateFlags & Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_TRANSFERRING))
            return;

        if (!this._pwmgr._remember)
            return;

        var domWin = aWebProgress.DOMWindow;
        var domDoc = domWin.document;

        // Only process things which might have HTML forms.
        if (!(domDoc instanceof Ci.nsIDOMHTMLDocument))
            return;

        this._pwmgr.log("onStateChange accepted: req = " +
                        (aRequest ?  aRequest.name : "(null)") +
                        ", flags = 0x" + aStateFlags.toString(16));

        // Fastback doesn't fire DOMContentLoaded, so process forms now.
        if (aStateFlags & Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_RESTORING) {
            this._pwmgr.log("onStateChange: restoring document");
            return this._pwmgr._fillDocument(domDoc);
        }

        // Add event listener to process page when DOM is complete.
        domDoc.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
                                this._domEventListener, false);
        return;
    },

    // stubs for the nsIWebProgressListener interfaces which we don't use.
    onProgressChange : function() { throw "Unexpected onProgressChange"; },
    onLocationChange : function() { throw "Unexpected onLocationChange"; },
    onStatusChange   : function() { throw "Unexpected onStatusChange";   },
    onSecurityChange : function() { throw "Unexpected onSecurityChange"; }
},
```

I've tried commenting out/deleting whole portions of the file, only to have the error re-appear.

Any help would be totally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were you trying to "View Selection Source" when this error happened? I recently was having this same issue (with no noticeably problematic side-effects) and [this blog post (May 2009)](http://chris.weekly.org/blog/2009/05/11/firefox-and-ns_error_not_implemented) seems to be relevant. Looks like it's an error within Firefox that Firebug is just picking up in its console.

Although my error was on line 328 of nsLoginManager (Firefox 3.5.9), it was for the same problem: `Component returned failure code: 0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) [nsIRequest.name]`

Comment: Apparently so! I was still noticing the issue, and just chalked it up to gmail refreshing or something. After reading your comment, though, I just went and tried it and - viola! Right-click > view source = nsloginmanager error. Bravo, and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That could be an extension having problems.  I've seen a number of extensions cause junk to end up in the javascript console.  Usually it's not actually breaking anything, but it can be annoying to filter out the noise.

Try disabling each of your extensions and see if that makes it go away.  If it does then you can start re-enabling them one at a time to find out which one is causing the problem.

Comment: I did this... Only running extension is Firebug :/

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Flash plugin upgrade was the cause of this problem for me - well, at least it started happening straight after the upgrade.

Comment: It may be coincidence; I still have the issue but only when I highlight > view selection source. It never fails...

Answer (score 0):

Firebug 1.6b1 plus Firebug > Firebug Icon Menu > Options > Reset All has worked for other users with this problem.